# × Trying to run parcel index.html No entries found at Bundler.bundle

Tags: bundle, parceljs

Trying to run parcel index.html 
No entries found 
at Bundler.bundle()

```
parcel index.html
Server running at http://localhost:1234
×  No entries found.
     at Bundler.bundle (file_location of bundler)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is over a year old but incase someone is googling this problem and having the same problem like me.

Try to include babel in your package.json and make sure you have a .babelrc file in your project. Mine Looks like this:

.babelrc

```
{"presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]}
```

package.json

"dependencies": {

```
"@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
"parcel": "^1.12.4",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

}

Hopefully that works.

More information here if you need it: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2095